# Vue.js - v-model not tracking changes with dynamic data?

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following form where the input fields are dynamically generated however when I update the fields the two way binding isn't happening - nothing is changing when i view the results in dev tools?

```
   <template v-for="field in formFields" :key="field.name">
        <div class="form-group" v-if="field.type == text'">
            <label class="h4" :for="field.label" v-text="field.label"></label>
            <span class="required-asterisk" v-if="field.required"> *</span>
                   <input :class="field.className"
                          :id="field.name"
                          :name="field.name"
                          type="text"
                          :maxlength="!!field.maxLength ? field.maxLength : false"
                          v-validate="{ required: field.required}"
                          :data-vv-as="field.label" 
                          v-model="form[field.name]"/>
           <span class="field-validation-error" v-show="errors.has(field.name)" v-text="errors.first(field.name)"></span>
         </div>
   </template>
```

And the following vue instance:

```
export default {

   props: ['formFields'],

   data: function () {

       return {
          form: {},
       }
   },

   created: function() {
        this.resetForm();
   },

   methods: {

     resetForm: function() {

            this.form = {
                'loading': false
            }

            _.each(this.formFields,  (field) => {
                this.form[field.name] = field.value;
            });

           $('#editModal').modal('hide');

           this.errors.clear();
     }
  }
}
```

When I hard code the values in the `form` it seems to work:

```
 this.form = {
                'loading': false,
                'Subject': 'Test',
                'Author': 'Roald Dahl'
            }
```

So it seems like something to with the following which it doesn't like:

```
  _.each(this.formFields,  (field) => {
                this.form[field.name] = field.value;
  });
```

Could it be something to do with the arrow function. Any ideas chaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into a limitation of Vue's reactivity, which is spelled out in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats)

Instead of

```
this.form[field.name] = field.value;
```

use

```
this.$set(this.form, field.name, field.value);
```

Comment: This is really helpful, BTW, in this case re-construction whole data & re assigning to `this.form` also work, but your way is good I think

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the following:

`<div class="form-group" v-if="field.type 'text'">` ->
`<div class="form-group" v-if="field.type == 'text'">`

and the model data object like this

```
data: {
          form: {},
   },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Jubels/eywraw8t/373132/ Example here. For testing purposes I removed the validation

Comment: sorry the first bit was a typo in my post. The model data object is `form: {}` however i need to reset the values if user makes some changes and cancels editing

Comment: the issue seems to be with setting the data. see my updated post, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
this.form[field.name] = field.value;
```

use

```
this.$set(this.form, field.name, field.value);

this.form.splice(field.name, 1, field.value)
```

or

```
Vue.set(this.form, field.name, field.value);

this.form.splice(field.name, 1, field.value)
```

More information in : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats